# Creating a for loop using increments of columns in r

Tags: r, for-loop, range, sequence, increment

I just started using r about 3 weeks ago and I need help. I hope I can explain this right.

I have a dataset where 4 columns represent the ratings to 1 stimulus. There are 55 stimuli, which totals 220 columns. I need to create a loop that goes through 220 columns in increments of 4 while completing the following function:

```
a<-rowMeans(dataset[1:4], na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(a)
mean(a, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I need the sum of each row for the columns and the mean of the sums. So essentially, I'm trying to achieve the following but in a condensed way:

```
a<-rowMeans(dataset[1:4], na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(a)
mean(a, na.rm = TRUE)

b<-rowMeans(dataset[5:8], na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(b)
mean(b, na.rm = TRUE)

c<-rowMeans(dataset[9:12], na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(c)
mean(c, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Please help in making my life easier. I need a loop so I don't have to manually do this 55 times.

Thanks in advance,
Yvette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new **dataframe** for your rowmeans and use the loop with bellow algorithm :

```
D <- data.frame(c(1:55),rep(0,55))

for( i in 1:55 )
{
   D[i,2]=Mean(rowMeans(dataset[,i*4-3:i*4],na.rm=TRUE),na.rm=TRUE)
}

Mean(dataset[,2],na.rm=TRUE)
```

In fact this code calculate row means of column means.

Comment: I received two errors:

   " Error in rowMeans(dataset[, i * 4 - 3:i * 4], na.rm = TRUE) : 
      'x' must be numeric "
and
   " In mean.default(dataset[, 2], na.rm = TRUE) :
      argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA "
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `for-loop` as such. There can be couple of choices based on name of the columns you have for `dataset` and the way your want your final result to be presented.

**Base-R:** A solution using `apply` and `aggregate`:

```
colMeans(t(apply(dataset, 1, function(x)
        aggregate(x, by=list(0:(length(x)-1) %/% 4), mean, na.rm = TRUE)$x)), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  5.5 15.5 25.5
```

**Option#2:** A `tidyverse` based solution. You need to rename your columns to represent `group`. Then convert data in long format using `gather`. Now, you can summarise data based on groups as:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset %>% setNames(paste("Group", ((0:(ncol(.)-1)) %/%4)+1, (1:ncol(.)),sep="_")) %>%  
  gather(Group, Value) %>%
  mutate(Group = gsub("_\\d+$","",Group)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Value = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Group     Value
# <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 Group_1  5.50
# 2 Group_2  15.5 
# 3 Group_3  25.5
```

**Data:**

```
Data is created to represent just `12` columns of the dataset mentioned by OP.

set.seed(1)
dataset <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:10,10),
                      col2 = sample(1:10,10),
                      col3 = sample(1:10,10),
                      col4 = sample(1:10,10),
                      col5 = sample(11:20,10),
                      col6 = sample(11:20,10),
                      col7 = sample(11:20,10),
                      col8 = sample(11:20,10),
                      col9 = sample(21:30,10),
                      col10 = sample(21:30,10),
                      col11 = sample(21:30,10),
                      col12 = sample(21:30,10)
                      )


dataset
#    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12
# 1     3    3   10    5   19   15   20   14   25    23    27    30
# 2     4    2    2    6   16   18   13   18   27    21    24    27
# 3     5    6    6    4   17   14   14   13   24    26    23    23
# 4     7   10    1    2   14   12   19   19   23    27    30    24
# 5     2    5    9   10   18   11   18   17   30    25    29    21
# 6     8    7    8    8   20   16   12   15   22    24    22    26
# 7     9    8    7    9   11   17   15   20   29    22    21    28
# 8     6    4    5    1   12   19   17   12   21    28    25    25
# 9    10    1    3    7   13   13   11   16   28    30    28    29
# 10    1    9    4    3   15   20   16   11   26    29    26    22
```

Comment: For both options I get the following error:

`In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Some of the columns have NA but I thought that's what `na.rm` was for.

Comment: @Eve It seems to me that column type in your is not numeric that's why mean is not calculated. Could you please check and let me know?

Comment: It states "integer"

Comment: @Eve Could you please share output of `dput(head(dataset))` so that I can try your solution here?